# Set-builder notation in graph theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

Let $G_x = (V_x, E_x)$ be a simple graph, where $$V_x = \{v_1 \in V \,\mid\, \exists v_2 \in V : v_1 \neq v_2 \mbox{ and } f(v_1, v_2) = x\}$$ and $$E_x = \{\{v_1, v_2\} \,\mid\, v_1, v_2 \in V_x \mbox{ and } f(v_1, v_2) = x\} \enspace ,$$ with $V$ being the list of vertices initially "unfiltered" by $f$ and $x$.

For me, that's a kind of redundant way of building both sets since, in both cases, the $f(v_1, v_2) = x$ condition is explicit. My question is: is there a more concise way of writing this down or is it perfect like that?

Answer (score 0):

Given a simple graph $G = (V, E)$ and some fixed $f$ and $x$, we can be a bit more concise by defining $G_x = (V_x, E_x)$ to be the subgraph induced by $V_x$. In symbols:
$$
G_x = G[V_x] = G[\{v_1 \in V \mid f(v_1, v_2) = x \text{ for some } v_2 \in V - \{v_1\}\}]
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a doubt though: does that definition ensure that all the edges in $E$ satisfy that $f(v_1, v_2) = x$?